# Delete Matching Elements in two Arrays - Python

Tags: python

```
def array_diff(a, b):     
    b_index=0 
    while b_index < len(b):
        for x in range(len(a)): 
            if b[b_index]=a[x]:  
                del a[x]
        b_index+=1
    print(a)

array_diff([1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7],[1,3,6])
```

causes a runtime error because i am mutating the container while still iterating over it 
what exactly will be the best practice to delete the matching items and return the list without the items

```
Initial List [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7]
Final List [2,4,5,7]
```

Comment: `set(a) ^ set(b)` will print `{2, 4, 5, 7}`

Comment: set removes duplicates in the list

Comment: Yes you are right I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can return the result in a new list:

```
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7]
exclude = [1, 3, 6]
result = [e for e in elements if e not in exclude]
# result == [2, 4, 5, 7]
```